# VB.NET - How to check if Webbrowser supports flash?

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a program which plays flash videos. However, I have to check if they have flash for the Internet Explorer (the WebBrowser Element) installed.

How can I check this? I saw this in another tool before, but I have no idea how it's working. :(

Comment: Why duplicate? He is asking about the server-side check using VB.NET, but the question you mentioned is about client-side check and javascript.

Comment: The answer could be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/903122/testing-for-flash-capability-on-the-server-side

Comment: @Egor4eg It's not possible to do this on the server-side. It's pointless to ask how to do it there. The OP should've done research first.

Comment: @xxbbcc It could be possible for some browsers. Browsers send HTTP headers to server and we can explore the headers in order to find indirect indicators of Flash existence. But I agree with you that OP should demosntrate his own effort in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try javascript

```
var _flash_installed = ((typeof navigator.plugins != "undefined" && typeof     navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"] == "object") || (window.ActiveXObject && (new    ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash")) != false));
```